# rails nokogiri no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Gemfile

```
...
gem 'nokogiri'
...
```

In controller

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://google.com'))
```

And I got a error

```
Errno::ENOENT in SiteController#scrap
No such file or directory - http://google.com
app/controllers/site_controller.rb:6:in `initialize'
app/controllers/site_controller.rb:6:in `open'
app/controllers/site_controller.rb:6:in `scrap'
```

I tried delete Gemfile.lock and do "bundle install" again, but it's not resolved my problems.

rails 2.3.8

ruby 1.9.3p194

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to `require 'open-uri'` if you want to pass URLs to `open()`. Additionally, you'll need to  read the file after opening it:

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://google.com').read)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to read the file though, it works without it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (ruby installed with brew), I do these steps to make `open()` works

```
require 'open-uri'

# to get a TempFile object
URI.open("http://www.google.com")

# to get string of html
URI.open("http://www.google.com").read
```

I got this from documentation at https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

Comment: This was the problem for me. It now needs `URI.open` rather than just `open`. You may not need to `require 'open-uri'` if it's in your Gemfile and being auto-required

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to access the http as a file in model.

```
For instance :
web_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.abokifx.com/", :ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE))
ERROR which was thrown 

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://www.abokifx.com/
    from (irb):10:in `initialize'
    from (irb):10:in `open'
    from (irb):10
```

As open is not able to read https URL as a file.
OpenURI is an easy-to-use wrapper for Net::HTTP, Net::HTTPS and Net::FTP.
It is possible to open an http, https or ftp URL as though it were a file, so you need to `require 'open-uri'`.

On adding `require 'open-uri'` Nokogiri was able to scrape the website.